# Ruby: Integer as key in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I need hash like:

`name[13][:sub_param1]` `name[13][:sub_param2]`

I've tried:

```
name = {13: {sub_param1 => 123}}
```

But it is only possible if 13: is '13': (string)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're doing here, but this works:

```
name = { 13 => { sub_param1: 123 } }
```

Note that using the `x:` notation means that the keys are forced to symbols. If you need to use more exotic key types, which is allowed, you must use the arrow.

Comment: Good catch. And looks like the ability to use pure integers as keys was added in Ruby version 2.0

Comment: @lurker You've been able to use *anything* as a key for as long as I can remember, it's been a core feature since pretty much forever. This does seem kind of insane if you come from a background like JavaScript where things are coerced to a string.

Comment: @lurker What docs? From the [1.8.7 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html): "A Hash is a collection of key-value pairs. It is similar to an Array, except that indexing is done via arbitrary keys of **any object type**, not an integer index. " I'm pretty sure it pre-dates 1.8 significantly as well.

Comment: I was keying (no pun intended) in on the phrase *...not an integer index* (following your bolded phrase) which was removed starting in 2.0. I suspect I misinterpreted that phrase. What does it really mean?

Comment: @lurker An Array can only use integer indexes, a Hash can use anything. I think the phrasing here was intended to mean "not *necessarily* an integer index". If it was removed it's probably because it was causing more confusion than intended.

Comment: Well, I guess it was a little ambiguous to me. If they were wording an exception, I would think they would have said, "not *necessarily* a symbol or string index" since that's the common use case. ;) But I stand corrected. Thanks.